# Camel get 304 response at second call only in browser and not with postman

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, apache-camel

I have a problem with a camel rest application.
The route returns the result I expect when called from PostMan, but from browser it returns the result the first time, whereas the second I get 304 error code with `HttpOperationFailedException`.

I've tried to remove/change headers such as `ETag`, `Expires`, `Last-Modified`, 
`Cache-Control`, `If-Modified-Since`, as I read in other answers to similar issues, but nothing has changed.

How can I avoid this error? And can someone explain me why I get it calling 
`http://localhost:8080/facebook/name` only from browser and not from PostMan?
If I try to call directly in browser `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/1234567?fields=name&access_token=ABCD1234MYTOKEN` there are no problems.

Here follows the code:

The route is defined in TriggerRouteBuilderClass:

```
package it.mycompany.facebook.service.camel.route;

import static javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod.GET;
import static org.apache.camel.Exchange.HTTP_METHOD;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import it.skytv.facebook.client.types.FacebookApplication;

@Component
public class TriggerRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() {

    restConfiguration()
            .apiContextPath("/api-docs")
            .apiProperty("api.title", "Camel REST API")
            .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0")
            .apiProperty("cors", "true")
            .host("localhost")
            .port(8080)
            .apiContextRouteId("swagger-api-doc")
            .component("servlet")
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

    rest("/facebook")
        .get("/name")
        .description("Gets the name of the Facebook application")
        .route().id("get-app-name-route")
        .removeHeaders("CamelHttp*")
        .setHeader(HTTP_METHOD, constant(GET))    
        .to("{{facebook.api.base.url}}/{{facebook.appID}}?fields=name&access_token={{facebook.permanentToken}})")
        .unmarshal("model-jackson-dataformat")
        .end()
        .endRest();

    }
}
```

The configuration is:

```
package it.mycompany.facebook.configuration;
import org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScans;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScans({@ComponentScan("it.mycompany.facebook")})
public class FacebookConfig {

    private static Logger trace = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FacebookAsyncServerConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean servlet = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            new CamelHttpTransportServlet(), "/*");
        servlet.setName("CamelServlet");
        return servlet;
    }

    @Bean(name="model-jackson-dataformat")
    public JacksonDataFormat jacksonDataFormat() {
        JacksonDataFormat jackson = new JacksonDataFormat();
        jackson.setEnableJaxbAnnotationModule(false);
        jackson.setPrettyPrint(true);
        return jackson;
    }
}
```

And the main method is:

```
package it.mycompany.facebook;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyFacebookApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyFacebookApplication .class, args);
    }
}
```

The properties injected in the route are defined in application.properties and are:

```
facebook.api.version=v2.11
facebook.api.base.url=https://graph.facebook.com/${facebook.api.version}/
facebook.appID=1234567
facebook.permanentToken=ABCD1234MYTOKEN
```

Update: the headers of the request and response taken from the browser are:

Case OK:

```
General
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/facebook/name
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade  

Response Headers
accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/
xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 17 Jan 2018 15:49:13 GMT
ETag:"b2790db5428802fhf415v9735876g323403ua592"
Expires:Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
facebook-api-version:v2.11
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=15552000; preload
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
upgrade-insecure-requests:1
X-Application-Context:application:8080

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,
application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

Case 304:

```
General:
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/facebook/name
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Wed, 17 Jan 2018 15:54:41 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Application-Context:application:8080

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,
application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
If-None-Match:"b2790db5428802fhf415v9735876g323403ua592"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

Many thanks.

Comment: _“I've tried to remove/change headers such as [...]”_ - what, in the request made by your browser? How did you do that? // What caching headers are you currently returning? AFAIK browsers only send an If-Modified-Since, if the previous response included a Last-Modified - so I’d go and try to remove that first of all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Obviously I have removed the headers only from the camel application, not from the browser. I've updated the question with the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved removing the ETag from the response I get.
Thanks to the hint of @CBroe, I found out that the second request from the browser had the header "If-None-Match", checking the value of the "ETag" from the previous response.